# How to compare a longtext and date value in sql?

Tags: sql, date, text, compare

I have date value stored in format dd.mm.yyyy **as longtext**. I need to compare this value to `CURDATE()` within a `SELECT` statement. (Please, don't ask me why it is saved in longtext.) Is there any way to do it?

This piece of code is not working of course, but it illustrates what I want to do:

```
...
WHERE longtext_date_value <= CURDATE()
...
```

Comment: if it's mysql use str_to_date http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0280__Date-Time-Functions/STRTODATEstrformat.htm function with appropriate formatting and compare to current_date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sergey comments: if MySQL, you can simply use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date):

```
    ...
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(longtext_date_value,'%d.%m.%Y') <= CURDATE()
    ...
```